# JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText) unexpected character

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I keep getting an unexpected character error in the console for the line

```
var a = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
```

and I'm not sure why. Could this be why my textboxes aren't populating with the parsed data?

Main page code:

```
function loadDoc()
{
   var xmlhttp;

   // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
   if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
   {
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
   }
   // code for IE6, IE5
   else
   {
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }

   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
   {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
      {
         var doc = window.document.createElement("doc");
         var a = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
         document.getElementById("textbox").innerHTML=a.first;
         document.getElementById("textbox2").innerHTML=a.second;
      }
   }

   xmlhttp.open("GET","loadTextBox.php?id=4",true);
   xmlhttp.send();
}
```

loadTextBox.php code:

```
<?php
---Placeholder for correct DB login info---

$result = $mysql->query(---Placeholder for correct SQL query---);

while ($row = $result->fetch_object())
{
   $queryResult[] = $row->present_tense;
}
$textboxValue = $queryResult[0];
$textboxValue2 = $queryResult[2];
echo json_encode(array('first'=>$textboxValue,'second'=>$textboxValue2));
?>
```

Comment: Are you sure you're getting a json object back and that the script in loadTextBox.php is not breaking?

Comment: What does `console.log(xmlhttp.responseText);` outputs?

Comment: After this line `if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){` add `alert(xmlhttp.responseText);` and share you get in alert box.

Comment: I tried console.log(xmlhttp.responseText); and it gave me an Inspect Network Request box which I don't understand.

Comment: alert(xmlhttp.responseText); gives this output <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>


</body>
</html> {"first":"radim","second":"radi"}

Comment: So you're outputting html before your json object. that's your problem. Have you given us the full loadTextBox.php code?

Comment: That's.... that's not JSON.  JSON.parse expects something explicitly in JSON format.  Otherwise it dutifully complains.

Comment: Yes I gave all of the loadTextBox.php code

Comment: Your response is mixed up with HTML and JSON data which is not JSON. JSON.parse() will fail parsing the JSON. Try remove the HTML tags `<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <body> </body> </html> ` and try again.

Comment: How would I make it into JSON format?

Comment: there must be html tags in `loadTextBox.php`

Comment: @Erik You mean surrounding my php block?

Comment: from what you posted it's probably before your php block

Comment: show us the full code in `loadTextBox.php`, so that we can help you.

Comment: The other part of the loadTextBox.php is my DB login info. In my file that contains my DB login info I have <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

<?php
$db_username = placeholder;
$db_password = placeholder;
$db_host = placeholder;
?>

</body>
</html> ---Maybe this is why it's messing up?

Comment: yea, why do you have html in your db info file?

Comment: Yes, that is why it is messing up. You will have to remove it.

Comment: yes, that why it's messing up.

Comment: So should the db info file just contain what I consider the "placeholders" from my comment above?

Comment: Yes, it should contain only the `<?php ...` part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `loadTextBox.php` file should not contain any HTML because the `JSON.parse` method expects only JSON:

```
<?php 
    header("Content-type: application/json");

    $db_username = placeholder; 
    $db_password = placeholder; 
    $db_host = placeholder; 

    $result = $mysql->query(---Placeholder for correct SQL query---);

    while ($row = $result->fetch_object())
    {
       $queryResult[] = $row->present_tense;
    }
    $textboxValue = $queryResult[0];
    $textboxValue2 = $queryResult[2];
    echo json_encode(array('first'=>$textboxValue,'second'=>$textboxValue2));
?>
```

If your DB login info is in a separate file, then there should be no HTML or BODY tags only the PHP tags.